# How to read from file and convert this specific file text into a <string, string> dictionary

Tags: c#, file, dictionary, io, windows-forms-designer

I would like to read from a .txt file and convert the text into a <string, string> dictionary. All I would like though is for the X and Y values to be stored, however, like <X, Y>.

How can I go about this with the current text file below that I have in-place?

```
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=359,Y=154}]
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=678,Y=230}]
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=625,Y=171}]
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=565,Y=314}]
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=409,Y=262}]
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=410,Y=59}]
[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=777,Y=151}]
```

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: I understand how to split the text up based on the comma values at the end between the X and Y values but I do not understand what to do with all of the rest of the text/how to handle everything that comes before {X=,Y=}. For example a File object would be perfect for this but I just do not understand how to implement it for this specific use case. If it were more of a simple format and there was only the X and Y values this would be significantly more easy for my brain. @FranzGleichmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a regular expression:

```
var s = "[System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal {X=359,Y=154}]";

var reg = new Regex(pattern: "{X=([0-9]*),Y=([0-9]*)}");

var match = reg.Match(s);
if(match.Success)
{
    var x = match.Groups[1].Value; // string "359" but you can use int.TrypParse to get a number
    var y = match.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer; it works flawlessly! Reg Ex is something I struggle with and this is a very clear and understandable explanation. Thank you for your time.